# I don't know why the value returned by atm.changeservicestatus() is false in customer.java?

Tags: java

-----ATM.java-----

```
public class ATM {
    int cash; 
    boolean inService;
    
    public ATM() {
        cash = 0;
        inService = false; 
    }
    public ATM(int x, boolean y) {
         cash = x;
        inService = y; 
    } 
    public int queryCash() {
        return cash;
    }
    public void increaseCash(int x) {
    cash = cash + x;
    }
    public void reduceCash(int x) {
        cash = cash - x;
        }
    public boolean getServiceStatus() {
        return inService;
    }
    public void changeServiceStatus() {
    
        if (inService) {
            inService = false;
            System.out.println("inService is now false");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("inService is now true");
            }   
        }
     public class CashDispenser {
        
    public void dispenseCash(int x) {
    reduceCash(x);
    System.out.println(x + " dollars has been dispensed.");
    }   
    }
     CashDispenser dispenser = new CashDispenser();
    public class ReceiptPrinter {
    public void printReceipt() {
        System.out.println("Receipt has been printed.");
    }
    }
    ReceiptPrinter printer = new ReceiptPrinter();
    public class CardReader{
        public void readCard() {
            System.out.println("Card has been read.");
        }
    }
    CardReader reader = new CardReader();
    public class KeypadDisplay{
        public void displayPINverification() {
            System.out.println("PIN has been verified.");
        }
    }
    KeypadDisplay display = new KeypadDisplay();    
}
```

------Person.java-------

```
public class Person {
     String name;
    
    public Person(){
        name = "default";
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String nameString) {
        
        name = nameString; 
        System.out.println("The name is set to "+ name);
    } 
}
```

--------Operator.java------

```
public class Operator extends Person {
    
    public void topUpATM(ATM atm) {
        
        System.out.println("Current inService is "+ atm.inService);
        System.out.println("Current cash is "+ atm.cash);
        
        if (atm.getServiceStatus() == true){
            atm.changeServiceStatus();
            
            System.out.println("ATM now has "+ atm.queryCash()+" dollars.");
        
            atm.changeServiceStatus();
            
        }
        if (atm.queryCash() < 5000){
        
            atm.increaseCash(5000);
            
            System.out.println("ATM now" + atm.queryCash()+ " dollars.");
            atm.changeServiceStatus();
        }
    
        
    }
    
}
```

---------Customer.java-------- **I dont know what am i doing wrong over here as this is the place where getserviceStatus() should return true but it is returning false. Other functions work perfectly so far but I am stuck on this issue for quite a while now and I cannot figure it out why is it that way. **

```
public class Customer extends Person {
    
    public void withdrawCash(ATM atm, int amount) {
        
        //atm.changeServiceStatus();
    System.out.println("Current inService is "+atm.getServiceStatus());
        if (!atm.getServiceStatus()) {
            System.out.println("ATM is not in service.");
        }
        else if (atm.queryCash()<amount) {  
            System.out.println("ATM has insufficient cash");
        }
        else {
            
         atm.reader.readCard();
         atm.display.displayPINverification();
         atm.dispenser.dispenseCash(amount);
         atm.printer.printReceipt();
            
         System.out.println(amount+" successfully withdrawn from ATM");
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

----------------A00.java------------

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A00 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int Number;
        System.out.println("Please enter between 0 and 10,000");
        Number = input.nextInt();       
    
     ATM atm_1 = new ATM (0,false);
     ATM atm_2 = new ATM (Number,true);
    
     input.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Please enter a name for the operator");
     String name = input.nextLine();
     Operator operate = new Operator();
     
     operate.setName(name);
     System.out.println("Processing ATM 1");
     
     operate.topUpATM(atm_1);
     System.out.println("Processing ATM 2");
     operate.topUpATM(atm_2);
     
     Customer cust = new Customer();
     String customer;
     
     System.out.println("Enter the name of a customer:");
     customer = input.nextLine();
     cust.setName(customer);
     
     
     System.out.println("Please enter the amount you want to withdraw: ");
     int withdraw;
     withdraw = input.nextInt();
     cust.withdrawCash(atm_1, withdraw);
     
     
     input.close();
     
    }
}
```

Comment: You print that it is true, but you don't actually set it true in that setter.

Comment: Are you familiar with the debugger features of your IDE?

Answer (score 1):

You recall the method `withdrawCash` passing `atm_1` as parameter and `atm_1` is istantiated as `ATM atm_1 = new ATM (0,false);`
The second parameter in ATM constructor sets `inService = false`